# Within a ReactJS component, when looping through a props array, I can only use the shorthand syntax for the loop. Why is this?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, scope

I can only use the shorthand syntax for iterators such as map and foreach, and I didn't find any answers online specifying this dilemma I ran into. I am literally 2 days in working with reactjs so bear with me. This is part of a Udemy course I am taking...

I had a problem, and by using the shorthand operator, no error occured. This obviously has something to do with the scope when rendering my component?
Its the Map function withing the Options component that I specifically am talking about

Original code with error

```
class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const title = 'Indecision';
      const subtitle = 'Put your life in the hands of a computer';
      const options = ['Thing one', 'Thing two', 'Thing four'];

      return (
        <div>
          <Header title={title} subtitle={subtitle} />
          <Action />
          <Options options={options} />
          <AddOption />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Options extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.options);
      return (
        <div>
          {  
            this.props.options.map((option)=>{
               <Option key={option} optionText={option}/>)
            }
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Option extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
      return (
        <div>
            {this.props.optionText}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Modified shorthand code without error:

```
  class Options extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.options);
      return (
        <div>
          {  
            this.props.options.map((option)=><Option key={option} optionText={option}/>)
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Option extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
      return (
        <div>
            {this.props.optionText}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is when you write it like this:

```
this.props.options.map((option)=>{
    <Option key={option} optionText={option}/>)
}
```

The curly braces define the *function block*, but there is no return statement. (Also it looks like you have a parenthesis/curly brace mismatch). You could try:

```
this.props.options.map((option)=>{
    return <Option key={option} optionText={option}/>
})
```

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement. See [Arrow Function - Function Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Comment: Got it, because the shorthand syntax has an implicit return statement and I wasnt declaring it within the block the long way. Completely overlooked that, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use arrow functions the basic syntax is as follows

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }
```

So basically, your problem stems from adding the curly braces without a return statement.

So this works:

```
this.props.options.map((option)=> {
    return <Option key={option} optionText={option}/>)
}
```

While this fails:

```
this.props.options.map((option)=> {
    <Option key={option} optionText={option}/>)
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @JBaczuk is correct, but to add a little more clarification, the shorthand syntax is not something from React, but from the [ES6 Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

From the Documentation:

> When the only statement in an arrow function is `return`, we can remove `return` and remove the surrounding curly brackets

So you could either write this:

```
elements.map((element) => (element.length));
```

or this:

```
elements.map((element) => {
    return element.length
});
```

Another thing with the Arrow Function syntax is:

> When there is only one parameter, we can remove the surrounding parentheses

Which means that this is also valid:

```
elements.map(element => element.length);
```

More details in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions).

Comment: Yes I am familiar with it, and implicit returns on built in iteration functions with ES6, just completely overlooked with the syntax of es6 classes and new reactJS material. Thanks for the help